# How to I use a getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, getActivity()); using fragment? - ...implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>

Tags: android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

Please, I tried a lot but no solution so far.

This is what I want and I have implemented the LoaderManager already but nothing and below is my only error

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, **getActivity()**);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you could use this.. But it seems to work for me.

Within the `Fragment.java` file,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_ACTIVITY_XML_FILE, container, false);

    // Your other codes here.... like setting up of adapters and all

    LoaderManager loaderManager = getActivity().getLoaderManager();  // Seems like within the Fragment files, `getActivity()` will reference the original activity. 
    loaderManager.initLoader(CARPARK_LOADER_ID, null, this);
    return rootView;
```

Answer (score 0):

in what class you did this? what your class implements? what LoaderManager you imported in your class(android.app or android.support.v)?